# Is there way to omit `--app` option by using current directory config?

Tags: heroku

When using `heroku` command I'm typing app name like:

`heroku config --app my_project1`

But I prefer to use config file for it like `Gemfile`.
Is there a config file that is autoloaded when heroku command is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Heroku toolbelt CLI uses git configuration to specify the default application in any given project directory.

For example if your `my_project1` Heroku app is set up with a git remote called `heroku` you can set it to be the default app with:

```
git config heroku.remote heroku
```

The config file will be in your `.git/config`.

There is more detail at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments